# How to pass value from a loop to a managed Bean?

Tags: jsf

I am trying to pass values from a loop to a managed Bean. And get the value back in view page. This is what I'm trying to do:

If I do this, it just prints the value on UserPage.xhtml

```
<ui:repeat var="userGrp" value="#{printUser.userGroups}">
    <h:outputText value="#{userGrp.name}"/> 
    <br/>                                           
</ui:repeat>
```

Userpage.xhtml

```
<h:link value="Group" outcome="userDetails">                    
    <ui:repeat var="userGrp" value="#{printUser.userGroups}">
      <f:param name="uGroups" value="#{userGrp.name}"/>                                             
    </ui:repeat>
</h:link>
```

How can I get those values on other page?
Thats what I'm doing at the moment, and it's not working:

```
<ui:repeat var="userGrp" value="#{param.userGroups}">
    <h:outputText value="#{userGrp.name}"/> 
    <br/>                                           
</ui:repeat>
```

Help!